# Newer Lottie files don't work with React Native on Android? How to export as legacy?

Tags: android, json, react-native, animation, lottie

Alright, Im using Lottie with React Native expo and have exported animations I made in AfterEffects as json using the Bodymovin plugin. I `import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native'` and they work fine on iOS.

Issue is, I get this error when running on Android https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/issues/473

This answer points to the issue being newer versions of Lottie, so I went on the Lottie site and found older animations, and they have no issues on Android.
So I went into Bodymovin Advanced settings and ticked the "legacy" box, and exported. But my animations still crash on Android.

What is wrong with my animations?

EDIT this is the json:

```
{"v":"5.6.5","fr":60,"ip":0,"op":36,"w":184,"h":184,"nm":"navdot","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"Ellipse 10","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":36,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[92.25,90.75,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667,0.667,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":0,"s":[147,147,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.667,0.667,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":9,"s":[160,160,100]},{"t":16,"s":[0,0,100]}],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"d":1,"ty":"el","s":{"a":0,"k":[37,37],"ix":2},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3},"nm":"Ellipse Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse","hd":false},{"ty":"op","nm":"Offset Paths 1","a":{"a":0,"k":-11,"ix":1},"lj":1,"ml":{"a":0,"k":4,"ix":3},"ix":3,"mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Offset","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Ellipse 10 Stroke","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"d":1,"ty":"el","s":{"a":0,"k":[37,37],"ix":2},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3},"nm":"Ellipse Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse","hd":false},{"ty":"fl","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":4},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":5},"r":1,"bm":0,"nm":"Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Ellipse 10 Fill","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":2,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":3600,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":4,"nm":"Ellipse 9","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[92.25,90.75,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667,0.667,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":16,"s":[0,0,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.667,0.667,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":27,"s":[150,150,100]},{"t":35,"s":[147,147,100]}],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"d":1,"ty":"el","s":{"a":0,"k":[73,73],"ix":2},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3},"nm":"Ellipse Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":34,"ix":5},"lc":1,"lj":1,"ml":4,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"op","nm":"Offset Paths 1","a":{"a":0,"k":-11,"ix":1},"lj":1,"ml":{"a":0,"k":4,"ix":3},"ix":3,"mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Offset","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Ellipse 9 Stroke","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"d":1,"ty":"el","s":{"a":0,"k":[73,73],"ix":2},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3},"nm":"Ellipse Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Ellipse 9 Fill","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":2,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":3600,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":3,"ty":4,"nm":"Shape Layer 1","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[92,92,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ty":"rc","d":1,"s":{"a":0,"k":[151.469,146.914],"ix":2},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"nm":"Rectangle Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Rect","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"lc":1,"lj":1,"ml":4,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[-0.361,0.123],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[81.225,83.721],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Rectangle 1","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":3600,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}
```

Comment: where's the lottie animation .json file?

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior check my edit

Answer (score 0):

So, i tried your lottie file and she's empty.

On my project, every lottie is doing ok, so i guess the solution for your project is:

On your `package.json`, replace your `lottie-react-native` version to `^3.3.2`
then, with a terminal on your project root folder, run: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install --save` (or `yarn install` if you're using yarn instead of npm)

Then, replace your lottie file using any file you can download as json on [lottiefiles](https://lottiefiles.com/)

This should work

Comment: this didnt work .. I believe its an issue with the json files I am exporting. I know for a fact the json file in my answer (edited) is not blank

Comment: So, create an account on lottiefiles, drop the file here: https://lottiefiles.com/preview
And see if the file is empty or not.

Comment: I did. It isnt empty

Answer (score 0):

```js
This finally worked for me

import { Animated, Easing } from "react-native";

  const animationProgress = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
  const AnimatedLottieView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(LottieView);


 useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(animationProgress.current, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 5000,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      })
    ).start();
  }, []);


 <AnimatedLottieView
        // autoPlay
        loop
        style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}
        source={require("../assets/data.json")}
        progress={animationProgress.current}
      />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).